# Find the coefficients such that all four roots of $(x^2-px+q)(x^2-qx+p)$ are natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, roots, alternative-proof

> Find all ordered pairs $(p,q)$ of natural numbers such that all $4$ the roots of $$f(x)=(x^2-px+q)(x^2-qx+p)$$ are natural numbers.

I got a solution of the problem (see below) but I want some alternatives.

#### My solution

Let $f(x)=(x^2-px+q)(x^2-qx+p)$. Since both quadratics must be nonnegative at $x=1$,  $f(1)\ge 0$. Putting $x=1$, we get $(1-p+q)(1-q+p)\ge 0$. After simplifying this we get $(p-q)^2 \le1$, which implies that either $p-q=1$ or $p=q$ or $q-p=1$.

Let the roots of $x^2-px+q$ be $m,n$ and of $x^2-qx+p$ be $r,s$. Consider $p=q$, so $m+n=mn$ therefore $m=n=2$ which implies $p=q=4$. Now consider $p-q=1$, so $m+n-mn=1$, leading to infinite solutions, so looking at $x^2-qx+p$, $r+s=q$ and $rs=p$, so $rs-(r+s)=1$ giving $r=3 $ and $s=2$. So $p=6$ and $q=5$.

Similarly if we proceed with $q-p=1$ we get $q=6$ and $p=5$. Hence the pairs are $(4,4)$, $(5,6)$, $(6,5)$.

Comment: Well, we won't know what "alternative" is unless we know your answer!

Comment: (4,4),(5,6),(6,5)

Comment: Are $p,q$ supposed to be primes? Or any nonnegative integers? (or did you mean positive integers?)

Comment: I should be clearer... we should know how you *found* your answer.

Comment: p and q are positive integers.

Comment: I solved the problem, but do not know if it is an alternative, so I can't pose an answer.

Comment: I request Calvin to post his solution if it is different from mine.I used the idea that value of both the quadratics must be a non-negative real number at x=1.Then we get a sufficient condition on p and q.

Comment: @WarmFuzzies My solution is similar to both  OP and Peter's. To me, they are equivalent. I treat "understanding $ab - (a+b) + 1$ via Veita" as equivalent to "remainder factor theorem (1-a)(1-b) = f(1)" as equivalent to "substituting $ x = 1$ in the quadratic equation".

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take at the problem. Let $a\leq b$ be the roots of the first equation and $c\leq d$ of the second one. [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) then tell us that
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
a+b & = & p & = & cd \\
c+d & = & q & = & ab \\
\end{array}$$

Adding the two and moving everything to one side yields
$$ab + cd - (a+b) - (c+d) = 0$$
or, equivalently, 
$$(a-1)(b-1) + (c-1)(d-1) = 2$$

There are three possibilities:

- Either $(a-1)(b-1) = (c-1)(d-1) = 1$, which implies $a=b=c=d=2$ and $(p,q)=(4,4)$,
- or $(a-1)(b-1)=2$ and $(c-1)(d-1)=0$, yielding $(a,b,c)=(2,3,1)$ which produces $(p,q)=(5,6)$ (and $d=6$),
- or the pairs $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are swapped, so $(p,q)=(6,5)$ and $(a,b,c,d)=(1,6,2,3)$.

Comment: But how do you know whether this is an alternative to the author's (alleged) way of solving the problem?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The last comment from the author states: "I used the idea that value of both the quadratics must be a non-negative real number at $x=1$"; an observation my approach doesn't make explicit use of.

Comment: Good enough. I'm still not convinced, though, that OP has a solution.

Comment: Well done Peter,my solution:Let f(x)=(x^2-px+q)(x^2-qx+p),as I said,f(1)>=0,putting x=1,we get (1-p+q)(1-q+p)>=0.After simplifying this we get (p-q)^2 <=1,which implies that either p-q=1 or p=q or q-p=1.Let the roots of x^2-px+q be m,n and of x^2-qx+p be r,s.Consider p=q,so m+n=mn therefore m=n=2 which implies p=q=4.Now consider p-q=1,so m+n-mn=1,leading to infinite solutions,so looking at x^2-qx+p, r+s=q and rs=p,so rs-(r+s)=1 giving r=3 and s=2 so p=6 and q=5.Similarly if we proceed with q-p=1 we get q=6 and p=5.Hence the pairs are (4,4),(5,6),(6,5).Yes I accept that it is a lengthy one.